# How can I implement a Homomorphic filter in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, homomorphic-filter

I have taken the source code from [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21357-homomorphic-filtering) and tried to modify it to fit my need. But, the filter is not working as expected. I am not being able to find the issue in my code.

**What is the issue with my modified code?**

*Expected Output*

[image]

*Actual Output*

[image]

---

*Source Code*

**main.m**

```
clc
close all
clear all
d=10;
order=2;
im=double(imread('tun.png'));
subplot(121)
imshow(im./255);
[r, c]=size(im);
j = homofil(im,d,order);
imshow(j);
```

**homofil.m**

```
function output = homofil(I, d, n)
    I = double(I);

    H = butter_hp_kernel(I, d, n); 

    alphaL = .0999;
    aplhaH = 1.01;
    H = ((aplhaH-alphaL).*H)+alphaL;
    H = 1-H;

    im_l = log2(1+I);
    im_f = fft2(im_l);
    im_nf = H.*im_f;
    im_n = abs(ifft2(im_nf));
    output = exp(im_n);
```

**butter_hp_kernel.m**

```
function k = butter_hp_kernel(I, Dh, n) 
    Height = size(I,1); 
    Width = size(I,2); 

    [u, v] = meshgrid( ...
                    -floor(Width/2) :floor(Width-1)/2, ...
                    -floor(Height/2): floor(Height-1)/2 ...
                 ); 

    k = butter_hp_f(u, v, Dh, n);

function f = butter_hp_f(u, v, Dh, n)
    uv = u.^2+v.^2;
    Duv = sqrt(uv);
    frac = Dh./Duv;
    %denom = frac.^(2*n);
    A=0.414; denom = A.*(frac.^(2*n));    
    f = 1./(1.+denom);
```

---

*Input Image*

[image]

Comment: Flagged with a good duplicate. It segments license plate characters using homomorphic filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a more detailed explanation and stackoverflow went into maintenance and I couldn't post. So here's the one-line explanation.

Your j is the wrong range: [1, 1.08]  so it shows white.
Do `imshow(j, [])` or convert j with `mat2gray`

Comment: I am facing a continuous trouble with these two things: (1) `double` <--> `uint8`, (2) `imshow(I, [])`.  I just can't understand which is required when. For instance, butterworth filters require I convert double to uint8, but some images do not show up. Now, I am stuck with this.

Comment: uint8 images take values of type uint8 from 0 to 255. double images take values of type double from 0 to 1. To properly convert a uint8 image to a double one in the right range, use `im2double`.

Comment: the `[]` in imshow simply uses the minimum and maximum range of the matrix as the black and white (i.e. it scales the contrast to match that range). If you don't give a range, then imshow will rely on the type (uint8 / double) to show the appropriate range.

Comment: Yes I know. But, the problem is, I am not understanding which is needed when.

Comment: I would work with double precision whenever possible. If a function explicitly requires uint8 convert to that, but be careful when dividing as you might get roundoff. But, in general, as long as you are treating the range you expect an image to be, in general both forms are fine.